# How to create a button in JavaScript? and using that button for OpenERP method?

Tags: javascript, odoo, openerp-7

I want to access OpenERP method using JavaScript button, I created a button in tree view, it was placed in wizard. In normal OpenERP not support button in (wizard) tree view. So I need to create JS button for this process.

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean like mine below:

[image]

I did this with:

```
<tree string="" editable="bottom">
   .......
   <button name="teggu_pajek" type="object" string="Teggu Pajek" icon="terp-stock_zoom"/>
   .......
</tree>
```

Comment: HI thanks...But,it is not working for my case,in tree view the record get values from onchange,in that case the record is not saved in database,this situation the button gets not editable mode,so I cant process that operation completely .